# Functional form of Delta function to perform convolution of continuous functions

Tags: convolution

I'm trying to get Mathematica to perform the convolution I need. I think it's fairly simple, just a convolution between a `Normal` distribution and a `Uniform` distribution on `[-1,1]`. A friend of mine mentioned using the delta function to do so but I'm not sure how to evaluate it correctly in Mathematica... Below is my attempt:

```
Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ]][x-y](DiracDelta[# + 1] + DiracDelta[# - 1])/2&[y], 
 {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

However, the output when I plot the solution seems readily wrong. I believe my problem is in how I'm implementing the `DiracDelta`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apparently this is a mis-interpretation of $[-1,1]$. It's an interval, right? Then you mean a uniform distribution **on** $[-1,1]$... so deltas are wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what is being asked. Is there some reason to believe that the result of the `Integrate` above is not correct? I get: `(E^(-((1 + x - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))) + E^(-((1 - x + \[Mu])^2/( 2 \[Sigma]^2))))/(2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] \[Sigma])` and it seems to behave as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I would proceed as follows.  Define a transformed distribution.

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[
   x + 2 y - 1, {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ],
     y \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[1/2]}];
```

This has the expected properties

```
{Mean[dist], Variance[dist]}
(* {μ, 1 + σ^2} *)
```

and the PDF can be computed easily

```
PDF[dist, x]
(* (E^(-((1 + x - μ)^2/(2 σ^2))) + E^(-((1 - x + μ)^2/(
  2 σ^2))))/(2 Sqrt[2 π] σ) *)
```